# Editing Laravel plugin

Tags: php, laravel, github, composer-php, git-fork

I'm new to Laravel and I've pulled a plugin into my project (https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-users) which I'd like to edit.

I made some edits to a file in vendor/jeremykenedy/laravel-users/src which had the desired effect but vendor is in Laravel's .gitignore so my changes aren't tracked. I could of course edit the .gitignore but I'd obviously not doing be things the right way.

I also tried copying the edited version of the file to my main App/Http/Controllers directory (keeping the same filename) in case Laravel has an overrides hierarchy or something, but no effect.

What's the correct way of editing Laravel plugin behaviour in a way that is tracked in git?

Edit: to clarify on the reason for this, I've added a new column to the users table (a 'type' column) and would like this to be editable and also to be able to enter something for the new field when adding a user.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously you shouldn't edit anything in `vendor` directory. You should fork package on github. Make changes in your fork and then set [VCS repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository) in composer.json

As you can read in there:

> There are a few use cases for this. The most common one is maintaining
>   your own fork of a third party library. If you are using a certain
>   library for your project and you decide to change something in the
>   library, you will want your project to use the patched version. If the
>   library is on GitHub (this is the case most of the time), you can
>   simply fork it there and push your changes to your fork. After that
>   you update the project's composer.json. All you have to do is add your
>   fork as a repository and update the version constraint to point to
>   your custom branch. In composer.json, you should prefix your custom
>   branch name with "dev-". For version constraint naming conventions see
>   Libraries for more information.

so this is perfect use-case for you.

So basically:

1. You should create fork of https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-users on github (there is `fork` button on top)
2. You should create your custom branch (for example `new-features`) and push any changes into this branch
3. you should add into `composer.json`:

   ```
   "repositories": [
      {
         "type": "vcs",
         "url": "https://github.com/YOUR-GITHUB-USER/laravel-users"
      }
   ],
   ```
4. You should make sure you have in `require` block of your `composer.json`:

   ```
   "jeremykenedy/laravel-users": "dev-YOUR_BRANCH_NAME"
   ```

   where `YOUR_BRANCH_NAME` matches branch name from step 2 (for example `new-features`) - keep in mind here it should be prefixed with `dev-`

Comment: @SaidbakR Thanks for info, I've fixed it

Comment: It will be so nice to support this great answer with code example.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to fork the original repository and add your changes to this repo, you can then create a pull request to the original repo in case this change is also useful for other users.

Of course they could decline your pull request so in order to make your changes available within your project you could register your fork on [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/submit). In your vendor file you can then reference to your version of the package.

IMPORTANT: Don't forget to mention the original repo and publisher in your repo as well as on packagist, he deserves credit for his code ;)